# writing a basic script that pings the current network

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ping

I'm having trouble writing a simple script that pings its current network. 
I want the output to look the same as a normal ping but I'm having trouble getting to that point

here's the original question from the assignment

-write a short script(using the ping command)to do a "ping" scan of your current network.

any help you can give is much appreciated

I originally tried `printf` but I wasn't able to even get a decent output so I gave up and started using echo

This is what I have right now

```
#!/bin/bash

for ping in $(ping -c 4 -v 192.168.1.10)
  do echo $ping
done
```

my teacher said that I would run into two problems with the simple ping script and that I could find the answer in the ping man pages. however I can't seem to find anything to help.

I basically want the script to run as if I just ran a normal ping command and have it display output in the same way.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to ping all the machines in the current network? such as 192.168.0.1/24?

Comment: correction- shebang should be #!/bin/bash

Comment: @ceving  its not related to this i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the question from your assignment, I would say what you need to do is invoking ping in all the IP's in your current network (192.168.1.0 in case it is a /24 mask).

What you are trying to do is a simple ping to 192.168.1.10.

If that is the case, why don't you just call ping command in your script?

```sh
    #!/bin/bash

    ping -c 4 -v 192.168.1.10
```

I think what your teacher really wants is you to find the way of making a loop over all the IP directions in your network.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash

ping= ping -c 4 -v 192.168.1.10
print $ping
```

simply get the out put

Comment: Could you edit your answer and include some explanation? Code-only answers are considered as low quality posts

Comment: This only makes it worse, by polluting the file system with an unnecessary temporary file.

Comment: i have changed it. now no unnecessary temporary file. :)